# How to create unique regions by intersecting closed paths in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Let's say I have a circle (A) with diameter slightly larger than the sides of a square (B), and A & B are aligned center-on-center. As these overlap, they will produce 9 separate regions. Is there any way to intersect the two curves/paths to produce these 9 independent regions/closed-paths such that I can fill/color each of the 9 regions independently?

I see in this link how to cut paths to color each stroke/line independently:
[https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90075/split-an-svg-based-on-intersecting-lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/380rN.png). But I'm interested in FILLING each region separately. Do I have to cut all the paths, and then manually create closed paths/regions from the newly cut paths, clicking on vertex-after-vertex, or is there a faster/better way?

EDIT:

I tried @Billy Kerr's excellent answer on some slightly more complicated shapes, (B-Spline Paths), and found that as per his suggestion I needed to convert the B-Splines to Bezier paths, using **Path + Object to Path** and now it works great!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's a reasonably fast way!

1. Draw your shapes
2. Select both shapes, do *Path > Combine* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. Note: the shapes will turn all one colour, but they are still there, just combined.
3. Draw a rectangle around both, and hit <kbd>End</kbd> (Send to bottom)
4. Select both pieces, do *Path > Division* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. Each piece becomes a separate shape which can have its own fill colour, or be moved or deleted independently

[image]

**Note:** I've used different coloured fills in the example above, but the colours don't matter, these are just so you can see what's going on.

**Edit after comments:** Don't use *Path > combine* on b-spline or spiro paths, because those are path effects. You'd need to convert them to normal Bézier paths before proceeding. To do that, select them and click *Path > Ojbect to Path*, then Combine will work as expected.

Comment: Many thanks. That's very helpful, however, when I tried this on some slightly more complicated paths -- B-Spline Paths in the case above (please see my edit to the original question), I got a mess after I did **Path + Combine**. Any ideas how to handle that? Tks!

Comment: @Crowdpleasr Hmmm . . . don't use this on b-Splines or Spiro paths - those are a path effects. You'd need to convert them to normal Bézier paths using *Path > Object to Path*, before proceeding.

Comment: Many thanks. That works perfectly now!

Comment: @Crowdpleasr - glad to please the crowd!!